# How do I make better httpd down checker?

Tags: apache

I have apache down checker script (remote server), but I think it doesn't work if httpd has a timeout issue or something similar.

For example, site was offline, but the server was online status.
Should I put timeout stuff or something else?  How??

```
<?php
function GetServerStatus($site, $port)
{
$status = array("OFFLINE", "ONLINE");
$fp = @fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
if (!$fp) {
    return $status[0];
} else 
  { return $status[1];}
}
?>

<?php
$status =  GetServerStatus('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',80);
    if($status == 'OFFLINE') {
    $message = "Server is down now!!";
}
?>
```

Comment: This depends on what you mean by "offline". Is "502 Sorry, I could not open a database connection" offline? Requesting the root page and checking it for a string "in the content area" is probably the most strict check for "aliveness" that I'd be willing to do: it shows that the server is alive, serving the root page with status 200, and its content is vaguely what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this can possibly report incorrectly. You could consider sending a GET / request and timing it out.

You could also consider closing the socket in the success case.